# Resizing Components with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a `JFrame` that contains two `JPanel` containers. In the below picture one panel is blue, the other contains a `JTable`. As can be seen, when I resize the frame, the frame (the blank gray area) expands. I would like the table panel to expand to fill this area.

[IMG http://i61.tinypic.com/2evujdj.png[/IMG]](http://i61.tinypic.com/2evujdj.png[/IMG])

What layout managers will accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BorderLayout` with the table in (a scroll pane) in the `CENTER` and button panel in the `PAGE_START` should do it.  Thought I'd probably use a `JToolBar` (instead of a `JPanel`) for the buttons.